# calling vbScript function from button input type

Tags: function, vbscript, asp-classic, referenceerror

I have the following function declared in the  tag of a classic asp page that i did not write but need to edit;

```
<SCRIPT language="VBScript">
sub confirmuser(sSubtype, sAction)

    ' this prompts user to confirm their action and sets hidden form fields.
    ' current subtypes are 1) Free Trial 2) Equity 3) Mutual Funds.
    ' current actions are 1) subscribe 2) unsubscribe

    sConfirmMessage = "Clicking on the OK button below will " & sAction & " login <%=rtrim(session("WebID"))%> " & _
        "to the " & sSubtype
    if sSubtype = "Free Trial" then
        sConfirmMessage = sConfirmMessage & "."
    else
        if sAction = "subscribe" then
            sConfirmMessage = sConfirmMessage & " Research Package at the stated rates.  This charge will appear " & _
            "on your commission statement."
        else
            sConfirmMessage = sConfirmMessage  & " Research Package."
        end if
    end if

    ' if they click OK, then they want to go ahead and process.  Save the necessary info
    ' in the two hidden form fields and post the form.
    if msgbox(sConfirmMessage, VBOKCancel, "Please Confirm") = 1 then
        window.frmSub.subType.value = sSubType
        window.frmSub.action.value = sAction
        window.frmSub.submit()
    end if

end sub


</SCRIPT>
```

and in HTML input that is trying to execute the function;

```
<CENTER><INPUT type='button' value='Sign Up' id='subaction' name='subAction' language='VBScript' onclick="vbscript:confirmuser('Equity','subscribe')"></CENTER>
```

when trying to click the button i receive the error of;

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmuser is not defined"
```

this functionality currently is working in the website, so i don't know why I am receiving these errors, but I am no classic asp/vbscript guru so i was hoping someone could help me out.

Comment: Which Web-Browser are you using?

Comment: the error is in chrome, but when trying in IE it doesn't work either, just doesn't give me any errors in the console.

Comment: I don't think you can run VBScript in Chrome. Even in IE you'll need to enable it somehow (Google it).

Comment: Nick, `language='VBScript'` isn't valid attribute unless assigned to a `<script>` tag. The `onclick` attribute should not contain `vbscript:` this was a moniker used in hyperlink `href` attributes to trigger script from the link, in the context of `onclick` it does nothing. Are you sure that code snippet is reaching your page (you said it's in an ASP page). Right click and view the source *(in the browser)* to see if the generated HTML contains `confirmuser()` function, my guess is it doesn't *(as the error suggests)*.

Comment: @haim770 Your right it won't work in Chrome but in IE it will work without any setting changes.

Comment: @Lankymart, It depends on the version and the enforced security policy.

Comment: @haim770 You could apply that to anything. But if you take vanilla Chrome and IE, Chrome won't support VBScript but IE will (right back to version 4!).

Comment: @Lankymart, My IE 11 refuses to run VBScript.

Comment: it appears that IE11 has deprecated VBScript as well as chrome so i am going to rebuild this using JS and re-build the page more efficiently, just seems at this point like the right way to go.  thanks for your help everyone

Comment: @haim770 That because in VBScript isn't "Standard" so in edge mode it won't. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/dn384057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I was also unable to get even a simple MsgBox to work. Given the code you provided being relatively straight forward, could you just convert it to javascript?